# How many integral ideals $\mathfrak{a}$ are there with the given norm $\mathfrak{N}(\mathfrak{a})=n$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

It is Exercise 1.6.1 in Jürgen Neukirch's number theory textbook(P38).
I think the number $n$ here means $[K:\mathbb{Q}]$, the degree of field extention for algebraic number field K.

I can image how simple this question is, but I was still floored by it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: so what is the question and context?

Comment: In algebraic number field K

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/410811

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to end this question, I demonstrate an example of cyclotomic field $K=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5)$, which is not so simple as a PID (equal as UFD in Dedekind domains) (Since it's well-known that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})\subset\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5)$, and $2^2=(\sqrt{5}+1)(\sqrt{5}-1)$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$).

Here consider $n=[K:\mathbb{Q}]=4$, the property of $\mathfrak{N}(\mathfrak{a})$ mentioned above implies that:

prime idea $\mathfrak{p}$ lying over $\mathfrak{a}$ $\Rightarrow$ $\mathfrak{p}\cap\mathbb{Z}=(2)$, and $\mathfrak{N}(\mathfrak{p})$ equals $2$ or $4$.

which is impossible
(since we can calculate the degree of $\mathfrak{p}$ by formula $2^f\equiv1(5)$ $\Rightarrow f=4$).

so the number is zero in the case. You can get similar result in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7)$ by the same method. Here $\zeta_n=e^{2\pi i/n}$.

Comment: This does not really answer the question though. I know there is a way to get an analytic estimate for the number of integral ideals of a given norm using the Dedekind zeta function, but is there a way to answer Neukirch's question exactly for an arbitrary number field?

Answer (score 3):

No, $[K:\Bbb{Q}]$ has nothing to do with it. You could rephrase the exercise as

> Given a fixed positive integer $n$, how many ideals are there with norm $n$?

**Hint:** You know that $\mathfrak{N}$ is multiplicative, i.e. that $\mathfrak{N}(\mathfrak{a}\mathfrak{b}) = \mathfrak{N}(\mathfrak{a})\mathfrak{N}(\mathfrak{b})$. Furthermore, you know that if $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$ such that $\mathfrak{p} \cap \Bbb{Z} = p$, then $\mathfrak{N}(\mathfrak{p}) = p^f$, where $f = [\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}:\Bbb{F}_p]$ is the relative degree of $\mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: And therefore I deleted my original comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The question nearly killed me...

Comment: I feel like these hints are insufficient to actually answer this question in the general case of an arbitrary number field. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2):

It’s a question of how the various rational primes split in $K$, and has relatively little arithmetic content, but looks to me more like a combinatorial problem. Let’s just look at $\Bbb Q(i)$, the Gaussian numbers, and its ring of integers $\Bbb Z[i]$.

The norm of an ideal $\mathfrak a$ of the ring of integers $R$ is the cardinality of $R/\mathfrak a$. The prime ideals of $\Bbb Z[i]$ are, as you probably know, $(1+i)$ above $2$, with norm $2$; the rational primes $p$ with $p\equiv3\pmod4$ and they are still Gaussian primes, they have norm $p^2$; and above each prime $p=a^2+b^2\equiv1\pmod4$, there are two primes, $(a\pm bi)$. Each of these has norm $p$.

So, in $\Bbb Z[i]$, there are *no* ideals of norm $15$ because there’s no prime of norm $3$. On the other hand, there are $2$ primes of norm $45$, namely $(3(2+i))$ and $(3(2-i))$. I think you can see where the combinatorial questions come in, especially in extensions of higher degree, where there will be rational primes that split completely into $[K:\Bbb Q]$ primes upstairs.

Answer (score 0):

This will perhaps wrap up any lingering doubts.

Let $K$ be any global number field (the degree of the extension is immaterial here) and $n$ be any natural number. For this particular question, we can assume that $n>1$, as the $n=1$ case is trivial. Writing $n=\prod\limits_{i=1}^r p_i^{a_i}$ into it's prime decomposition with $a_i's\in\mathbb{N}$ and $p_i,$ primes and defining $m_i:=\#$ prime ideals lying above $(p_i)$, $i\in\{1,\ldots,r\}$, we can reformulate the requirement as $\mathfrak{N}(\mathfrak{a})=\prod\limits_{i=1}^r p_i^{a_i}$. Thus the number of such $\mathfrak{a}'s$ will be $\prod\limits_{i=1}^r m_i$.